# "checking whether the C compiler works... no", and "configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables" on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: c, xcode, macos, terminal, configuration

I am trying to install PTAMM on my mac, and I have come across this error when trying to configure libcvd.

"checking for gcc... /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/myname/Src/libcvd-20100511': configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables See` config.log' for more details.
zsh: no such file or directory: /lib"

I have MacOS Big Sur 11.1, XCode 12.5.1.

I believe I have installed the developer tools, but when I run
"xcode-select --install"
I get the error
"xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates"

To remedy this I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling XCode developer tools, but that did not fix this error. Any advice?

Here is the config.log from configuration.

```
configure:2626: checking for gcc
configure:2653: result: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
configure:2882: checking for C compiler version
configure:2891: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 --version >&5
./configure: line 2893: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
configure:2902: $? = 127
configure:2891: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -v >&5
./configure: line 2893: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
configure:2902: $? = 127
configure:2891: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -V >&5
./configure: line 2893: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
configure:2902: $? = 127
configure:2891: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -qversion >&5
./configure: line 2893: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
configure:2902: $? = 127
configure:2922: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:2944: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -m32 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -m32 -arch i386 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -m32 conftest.c  >&5
./configure: line 2946: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
configure:2948: $? = 127
configure:2986: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "CVD"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "cvd"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.8"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "CVD 0.8"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2991: error: in `/Users/zacharywalker-liang/Src/libcvd-20100511':
configure:2995: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

Comment: Well, have you looked at config.log? Also, for what it's worth, I have no /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 on my Big Sur computers, so where did that come from?

Comment: I have no idea where /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 , came from (I am very new to this stuff). I just tried to download the latest version of XCode that wasn't a beta release and the developer tools with it.

Comment: Here is some config.log text "configure:2626: checking for gcc
configure:2653: result: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
configure:2882: checking for C compiler version
configure:2891: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 --version >&5
./configure: line 2893: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
configure:2902: $? = 127
configure:2891: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -v >&5
./configure: line 2893: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
configure:2902: $? = 127
configure:2891: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -V >&5
./configure: line 2893: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory

Comment: configure:2902: $? = 127
configure:2891: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -qversion >&5
./configure: line 2893: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
configure:2902: $? = 127
configure:2922: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:2944: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -m32 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -m32 -arch i386 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -m32 conftest.c  >&5
./configure: line 2946: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory

Comment: @zachwalker243 Please add that config.log text to the question rather than comments, and format it as a [code block](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), so it's readable.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Just put the config log text in the question, thank you so much for the advice! If you could please take a look that would be a lifesaver...

Comment: @zachwalker243 Is this the libcvd at [https://github.com/edrosten/libcvd](https://github.com/edrosten/libcvd)? If so, it looks like it has a `configure_osx_32bit` script that's over a decade old and set up to work on Mac OS X 10.6 (and cannot cope with any vaguely recent version of Xcode) (and you probably don't want 32-bit anyway). Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with the configure scripts, but you might have to remove that, bypass it, or maybe replace it with a newer/more relevant version.

Comment: @GordonDavisson thank you so much for the insight, I just figured that out too after hours and hours of searching... I tried to install XCode 9.4, which should run 32 bit, but that version is so old it doesn't seem to work on Big Sur. Seems like I am stuck unless I want to downgrade to a lower OS or contact libcvd to see if they can find a way to get it to work on newer versions. Thank you so much for you help, I really appreciate it!